# Which one of the following statements best describes the strings matched by the regex /\d([\d\_]+)/?

Tags: regex

1. Strings of one or more digits or underscores starting with a digit.
2. Strings of two or more digits or underscores starting with a digit.

This happened to be on one of my tests and I strongly feel that the answer is choice 'a' but the solution provided says 'b' to be the answer. Considering a string with "A number followed by an underscore" answer 'a' seems to be the best choice. Am I missing something?

[Test run on regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrUic.png)

Comment: why don't you do some test caes?

Answer (score 0):

the first digit must be an underscore

there must be **1 or more** (+) subsequent digits or underscores

the minimum number of characters is 2, therefore b is a better answer

Answer (score 0):

"+" represents one or more times the set  can be repeated. 
The given regex.  "/\d([\d \_]+)/?. Just examine the part '[\d \_]' it is not digit or underscore it is digit followed by underscore.
     (\d \_)    **digit followed by underscore**
     (\d + \_)  **digit or underscore**
So first character is digit followed by (digit and underscore) at least once. So it is a string of 2 or more digits or underscore, starting with a digit